# Angular 7 - toPromise não retorna erro

Tags: angular, httpclient

Estou utilizando o *HttpClient* conforme abaixo. Porem mesmo com erro 404 a `toPrimise()` entra no `.then()` ao invés do `.catch()`.

Obs: Em algumas vezes funcionou com o mesmo código. Acredito que seja algo relacionado ao `Observable` ser assíncrono e o `Promise` ser síncrono.

Alguém passou por isso ?

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

  export class LancamentoService {

     lancamentosURL = 'http://localhost:8080/lancamentos';

     constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

     excluir(codigo: number): Promise<void> {

         let headers = new HttpHeaders();
         headers = headers.set(
            'Authorization', 
            'Basic YWRtaW5AYWxnYW1vbmV5LmNvbTphZG1pbg==');

         return this.http
           .delete(`${this.lancamentosURL}/${codigo}999`, { headers: headers } )
           .toPromise()
           .then( response => null)
           .catch(error => error);
     }
}
```

**COMPLEMENTO**

Após alguns comentários entendi que `Observable` e `Promise` são assíncronos.

Analisando melhor o código após questionamentos, notei o seguinte: está gerando o erro no service, mas não está chegando no controller do componente como um erro.

No controller tenho a seguinte função.

```
private excluir(lancamento: any) {

    this.lancamentoSevice.excluir(lancamento.codigo)
      .then(response => {
        console.log('Response 2 : ', response );
        this.grid.first = 0;
        this.pesquisar();
        this.messageService.add({
          severity: 'success',
          summary: 'Sucesso',
          detail: 'Sucesso ao Excluir o lançamento : ' + lancamento.codigo });
      })
      .catch(erro => {
        console.log('erro 2: ', erro );
        this.errorHandlerService.handle(erro); } )    ;
  }
```

No service (`this.lancamentoSevice`) a função abaixo, que é a mesma descrita inicialmente neste post, porem com uns `console.log` para verificação

```
excluir(codigo: number): Promise<void> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Authorization', 'Basic YWRtaW5AYWxnYW1vbmV5LmNvbTphZG1pbg==');

    return this.http
      .delete(`${this.lancamentosURL}/${codigo}999`,  { headers: headers } )
      .toPromise()
      .then( response => {console.log('response: ' , response); return response; } )
      .catch(error => {console.log('error: ' , error); return error; });

  }
```

Na função excluir do service, cai no `.catch` retornando o seguinte erro:

```
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:8080/lancamentos/8999", ok: false, …}
```

Porem ao retornar a função excluir do controller, cai no `.then` ao invés do `.catch`

Foi neste ponto que não consegui evoluir.

Answer (score 1):

Ambas são assíncronas, o erro pode ser a maneira que o valor da API está retornando, por exemplo o Content-Type.

Comment: Alguma sugestão de como posso resolver?

Comment: O que está retornando dentro da função? Quando sucesso?

Comment: Vou ver certinho a noite o que retorna e posto aqui.

Comment: Postei um complemento. Se puderes dar uma olhada agradeço.

Comment: Eu não tenho certeza, mas eu acho que o problema é porque o erro existe na observable que faz a requisição para a API, porém quando você recebe ela no component e transforma em promise, não é mais um erro. Ele só vai. Você poderia tentar não usar o toPromise (subscribe) e continuar com observable que no caso do Angular é melhor utilizado.